# How can I interpret visualization of linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, prediction

This is my linear regression result it's an implementation of bigmarts sales prediction
I'm new to machine learning and I don't know how to interpret this result .. please if there is anyone explain this graph to me and I'll be so thankful
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wglCc.png)
 here is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
LR = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
predictors = train_df.columns.drop(['Item_Outlet_Sales', 'Item_Identifier', 'Outlet_Identifier'])
modelfit(LR, train_df, test_df, predictors, target, IDcol, 'LR.csv')
coef1 = pd.Series(LR.coef_, predictors).sort_values()
coef1.plot(kind='bar', title='Model Coefficients')
```

Comment: Details you've provided is not sufficient to understand what you've done. Can you please post you're code so we can see what you've done

Comment: I posted my code would see it again please

Answer (score 0):

In order to explain simply i will consider following Linear Regression hypothesis.

[image]

In here,

- `x1` , `x2`  are features
- `theta0` is the intercept term
- `theta1`, `theta2` are coefficients

You've plot a bar chart considering x axis as your feature values (`x1` & `x2` in  my case ) and y axis as your coefficient (`theta1` & `theta2` in my case) values. For each feature value there is a corresponding coefficient value.

So in the bar chart you've provided the coefficient of `Outlet_Type_0` is approximately `800`